# How to pass parameters to javascript function within a struts tag?

Tags: javascript, parameters, struts

something like this:

```
<s:iterator value="list" status="status">
  <s:textfield value="%{list_item}" onchange="js_func(this, **status.index**)"/>
<s:/iterator>
```

I wanna pass the index of status to js_func but fail to do that.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Try this?

```
<s:textfield value="%{list_item}" onchange="js_func(this, %{status.index})"/>
```